# Confusion around a (necklace) cobracket in Ginzburg's article Calabi-Yau Algebras

Tags: noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry

Something has been puzzling me for quite a while in Ginzburg's article [Calabi-Yau Algebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612139.pdf).

At some point he  considers the free graded algebra $\mathbb{C}\langle x_1, \dots, x_n, \theta_1, \dots \theta_n \rangle$ where the $x_i$ are of degree $0$ and the $\theta_i$ are of degree $1$ (he denotes it by $\mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)$, but the extra data is not relevant to my question).

He then considers the quotient of that algebra by the *subspace* of (graded) commutators and denotes the resulting vector space by $\mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc}$.

On page 23, he claims  that the vector space $\mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc}$ has an odd lie cobracket $\nu$ defined as follows:

If you have a cyclic word $ f = \vert f_1 \dots f_k \vert$, the map $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} : \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc} \rightarrow  \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)$ is the map where for every $f_j = x_i$, you first put $f_j$ in front using the cyclicity of $f$ (this costs a minus sign which depends on the degree of what comes before and after $f_j$  in $f_1 \dots f_k$) and then you "open" the cyclic word at the beginning, i.e you get $\pm f_{j+1} \dots f_k f_1 \dots f_{j-1}$. Same for $\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_i}$.

Similarly for $\alpha \in \{x, \theta\}$ there is map $\mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi) \rightarrow \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)\otimes \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)$, also denoted by $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha_i}$, which sends a word $f_1\dots f_k$ to

$$ \sum (-1)^{\vert \alpha_i \vert (\vert f_1 \vert +\dots + \vert f_{j-1} \vert )} f_1\dots f_{j-1} \otimes f_{j+1} \dots f_k$$ where the sum is taken over all $j's$ such that $f_j = \alpha_i$.

Now the cobracket $\nu  : \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc} \rightarrow \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc} \otimes \mathfrak{D}(F, \Phi)_{cyc}$  applied to the cyclic word $f$ is given by $$ \sum_i \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial \theta_i}- \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial \theta_i \partial x_i} $$ where the expression is taken modulo commutators.

The thing that bothers me is that Ginzburg claims that $\nu$ is an *odd* cobracket, i.e. a cobracket for the suspended vector space. However this is not the case. This can be seen if you consider a cyclic word $ \vert Ax_i B \theta_i C \vert$ where $A,B,C$ are words with no $x_i$ and no  $\theta_i$. Then the two terms corresponding to removing the $x_i$ and the $\theta_i$ may not have the good sign (i.e. one is not obtained from other by applying the graded swap operator on the suspended vector space).

This can be easily fixed by changing the formula to be
$$ \sum_i \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial \theta_i}- (-1)^{\vert f \vert} \frac{ \partial^2 f}{\partial \theta_i \partial x_i} $$ but now an other issue is that it does not form a Lie bialgebra anymore with the odd bracket described in the article.

This construction is supposed to be a generalization of the necklace bracket and cobracket or Schedler (see for example [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0406200.pdf)) to a graded setting, but I feel like there is no way to make it a  Lie super bialgebra. Or am I simply misunderstanding what it means to be super Lie bialgebra with an odd Lie bracket and odd Lie cobracket?